# sklean MLPClassifier: how to find relation/equation between output and input features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, perceptron

I am still in learning phase of sklearn and need some help in understanding how to come with a relation between output and input. Using data I was able to train sklearn MLPClassifier.

```
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes = (7,), random_state = 1)
#Print Coef
print clf.coefs_.shape
print clf.coefs_
```

The output looks like this:
[Output print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgQUe.png)

Any help will be useful. Thanks!!

Comment: in the screenshot I can see 2 different matrices. what do you want to know? what clf.coefs_ is ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `clf.coefs_` is a **list** with length `n_layers - 1`.

In your case, the length is 7-1 = 6.

The ith element in the list represents the weight matrix corresponding to layer i.

So if you type: `clf.coefs_[0]` this will return the weight matrix of the first layer.

More details [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html).

---

**EDIT**

The clf.coefs_ contains the weights that you need. Make sure that you understand how MLP works (see [HERE !](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html) )

A MLP looks like this:

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you very much for the insights!!
My coefs_[0] is a 7by7 matrix. Considering 7 input feature and 1 output feature, how do I come to calculate the weights contributed by each input feature towards output?

Comment: @blarredflunky see my edited answer. the clf.coefs_ contain the weights for each layer. Please find more details in the second link I posted